# Bootstrap Collapse loads collapsed on page load

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, load

the title pretty much covers the problem I'm having.

I've a list on a website I'm developing and I have hidden things within collapsible elements.

The problem I have is that they are already collapsed on page load.

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

Thanks for your comment Rob.

Figured it after looking through the HTML, I need to use `collapse` but all but one were using `collapse in` (or `collapse show` in bootstrap 4).

Problem sorted :)

**Load collapsed on page load :**

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
```

**Load hidden until clicked :**

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
```

Comment: as of Bootstrap 4, use `collapse show` : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/

Answer (score 10):

Bootstrap documentation says this:

> The collapse plugin utilizes a few classes to handle the heavy
> lifting:
>
> `.collapse` hides the content
>
> `.collapse.in` shows the content
>
> `.collapsing` is added when the transition starts, and removed when it finishes

Edit your HTML accordingly (use collapse.in instead of collapse)

Answer (score 2):

As of bootstrap 4.2.1 
if we want to show the collapsed content on load:

use **collapse show** class to the div or any element you want to show.

check the docs [Bootstrap Collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/)

Answer (score 0):

In **Bootstrap 5**, the class style `collapse show` is applied so that collapse is on on page load:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <a href="#demo" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="collapse">Collapse</a>

    <!-- Apply class style "collapse show" to collapse in on page load in Bootstrap 5. -->
    <div id="demo" class="collapse show"> &nbsp;
        Collapse
    </div>
        
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```